# how to find the sum in a nested tuple

Tags: python, tuples, swap

> Write a python program to define a tuple to accept 3 food product
> details such as Products name with their Price and Expiry date in a
> sub tuple, then  *find the sum of price of all products which are
> having same expiry date.*

```
t=(('CAKE', (748.0, '07-09-2020')), ('JELLY', (12.0, '07-09-2020')), ('CREAM', (244.0, '03-11-2020')))
```

Then, the output should be like

```
TOTAL PRICE:760
```

```
t=(('CAKE', (748.0, '07-09-2020')), ('JELLY', (12.0, '07-09-2020')), ('CREAM', (244.0, '03-11-2020')))
l=list(t);total=0
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    check=l[i][1][1]
    c=l.count(check)
    if c>1:
        total+=l[i][1][0]
print(total)
```

How to solve ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read How to Ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When you ask a question, please show what you have tried to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another answer already based on `defaultdict`, but I'm adding another one in order to show also how each of the data items can be unpacked directly into the relevant variables (`price` and `date`). The `_` here is a variable which will contain the description (e.g. `'CAKE'`) but because we are not using the value here, I am using the conventional name for a dummy variable instead of calling it `name` or whatever.

Using `defaultdict(float)`, the elements of the dictionary are created automatically as floating point zeros when they are first referenced.

```
from collections import defaultdict

t = (('CAKE', (748.0, '07-09-2020')),
     ('JELLY', (12.0, '07-09-2020')),
     ('CREAM', (244.0, '03-11-2020')))

totals = defaultdict(float)
for _, (price, date) in t:
    totals[date] += price

for date in totals:
    print(f'{date} {totals[date]}')
```

Gives:

```
07-09-2020 760.0
03-11-2020 244.0
```

Note that depending on your python version, the order of dates in the output might vary.

---

**Update:** you also asked how it can be done without using `defaultdict` -- like this:

```
totals = {}
for _, (price, date) in t:
    if date not in totals:
        totals[date] = 0.
    totals[date] += price
```

Comment: Is it can be solved without using using default dict ?

Comment: @Sush Yes of course, you can use a normal dictionary and test explicitly if the key exists or not. I will add to show you how this can be done.

Comment: @Sush Now added an update to show what you could do instead of using `defaultdict`.

Comment: Is there any change in my code that i should correct ?

Comment: There are various problems - (1) you are trying to use a variable `total` containing just a number but there are separate totals for each date, (2) the `count` is not going to work because it looks for elements that are equal to the thing you are searching for, whereas you are interested in content nested inside individual elements, (3) I'm not sure what the `c>1` test is for (what if there is exactly one)? I think that using a dictionary for the counts is the approach that you will need, so sorry not to be able to offer a solution that is more closely based on your existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, which was useful to analyse my mistake.No problem.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
from collections import defaultdict

t=(('CAKE', (748.0, '07-09-2020')), ('JELLY', (12.0, '07-09-2020')), ('CREAM', (244.0, '03-11-2020')))

data = defaultdict(int)
for entry in t:
        data[entry[1][1]] += entry[1][0]
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'07-09-2020': 760.0, '03-11-2020': 244.0})
```